# Convert facebook graph link to fql

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to convert

```
https://graph.facebook.com/100001186987234?fields=friends.uid(5718473123).fields(photos.type(uploaded).limit(10).fields(source,id,picture,link))
```

to an `fql` query.

Any one please explain how to convert this